# Importing Twilio in Flask app causes internal server error

Tags: python, azure, twilio

I am writing a simple web app using flask using Python 2.7 and hosting it on Microsoft Azure. The app works fine until I write the line "import twilio" in views.py. I deployed the app to Azure and now I am getting an error that says "The page cannot be displayed because an internal server error has occurred." I have twilio 5.6.0 included in requirements.txt

How can I fix this?

Comment: When you deployed to Azure did you install all the dependencies? Is there an error log from the app that you can share?

Answer (score 0):

I tried to find out the issue reason, and I discovered the issue seems to be caused by no permission by installing the `twilio` python package on Azure WebApp within the default runtime. When I tried to command `D:\Python27\Scripts\pip.exe install twilio` at the Kudu, I got the error information as below.

> error: could not create 'D:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\tests': Access is denied

On Azure WebApp, we can only do the operations in the path `D:\home`. So per my experience, here is my workaround way as reference for resolving this error.

1. Access the Kudu tool of your webapp via the url `https://<your webapp name>.scm.azurewebsites.net`.
2. Install a site extension `Python 2.7.12 x86` which will be installed at the path `D:\home` if using the 32bit version of Azure WebApp as example.
   [image]
3. Switch to the Kudu CMD, then you can see a new Python runtime which has been installed at here and you have permission to do any operations on it.
   [image]
4. Commands `cd Python27` and `touch get-pip.py` and copy the content of the url `https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py` into the `get-pip.py` via `Edit` button, then run `python get-pip.py` to install the `pip` tool.
   [image]
5. Command `Scripts\pip install twilio` to install `twilio` package.
6. Refer to the section `web.config` of the [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/web-sites-python-configure#webconfig) to change the default settings for Python runtime. **Change all default path value `D:\Python27` to `D:\home\Python27`.

Hope it helps.